# proper use of boost::wait_for_any

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio, future

I have a simple task scheduler: an execute method is called, and the `packaged_task` returns a pointer to my `Task`. When a Task has finished I' like to show debug data (the GUI is involved so I need to do this in the main thread). I'd like to use `boost::wait_for_any` for this like shown, however `j->get()` sometimes throws the exception `boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::promise_already_satisfied> >`. This leaves my with two thoughts. Either it's due to copying, which the exception class indicates, but I wouldn't see where this occures, or due to `get` being called already, which cannot happen as the futures are only visible in this method block and I already converted them to shared_futrues so it should work.

So in the `wait_for_any` part, how would I get back the pointer to the `Task` instance that has finished?

**Edit** using `future` instead of `shared_future`.

Turns out the exception was thrown in the `execute` function of one of my tasks and futures will carry those exceptions over to the `get` call. The code itself was fine (except for the missing exception handler). However using Boost Signals (see answer below) might be the better aproach.

```
std::vector<boost::future<Task*>> futures;
std::vector<Task*> tasks = get_tasks();
for (Task* t : tasks) {
    typedef boost::packaged_task<Task*()> task_t;
    task_t task([t]() -> Task* {
        t->execute();
        return t;
    });

    auto fut = task.get_future();
    futures.push_back(std::move(fut));

    impl->io_service.post(boost::bind(&task_t::operator(), boost::make_shared<task_t>(std::move(task))));
}


for (Task* t : tasks) {
    auto j = boost::wait_for_any(futures.begin(), futures.end());
    Task* task = j->get();
    task->display_debug();
    futures.erase(j);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mmm. I acutally lost track a little here. It seems you are doing things a bit more complicated than required (why don't you use Boost Signals2 instead of "polling" for specific "events" through futures? It appears you are not expecting them in any particular order anywway?).

For what it's worth, here's a fixed-up version that works for me. If I have more time later, I might compare notes to see what explains the difference.

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27a6022b2827ab29)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

struct Task
{
    virtual ~Task() = default;
    virtual void execute() {}
    virtual void display_debug() { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << static_cast<void*>(this) << "\n"; }
};

std::set<Task*> get_tasks()
{
    static std::set<Task*> data{ new Task, new Task };

    return data;
}

int main() {
    struct { boost::asio::io_service io_service; } impl_instance;
    auto impl = &impl_instance;

    std::vector<boost::shared_future<Task*>> futures;
    std::set<Task*> tasks = get_tasks();

    for (Task* t : tasks) {
        typedef boost::packaged_task<Task*> task_t;
        task_t wrap([t]() -> Task* {
            t->execute();
            return t;
        });

        auto fut = wrap.get_future();
        futures.push_back(std::move(fut));

        impl->io_service.post(boost::bind(&task_t::operator(), boost::make_shared<task_t>(std::move(wrap))));
    }

    boost::thread th([&]{ impl->io_service.run(); });

    while (!futures.empty()) {
        auto j = boost::wait_for_any(futures.begin(), futures.end());
        auto fut = *j;
        futures.erase(j);

        Task* task = fut.get();
        task->display_debug();

        // optionally:
        // tasks.erase(task);
    }

    th.join();
}
```

Comment: In case you're interested, here's a similar demo using Boost Signals: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f155fdcc19f25400)**

Comment: Turns out the exception was thrown in the `execute` function of one of my tasks and futures will carry those exceptions over to the `get` call. The code itself was fine (except for the missing exception handler). However using Boost Signals might be the better aproach.